# How to split a text box based on new lines on Sketch?

Tags: text, sketch-app, automation

Are there any ways/plugins to split a text box into multiple layers based on new lines / line breaks on Sketch?

[image]

Below is the result I want:

[image]

Comment: My immediate thought was that there has to be a script that does this, which is true: https://github.com/joshwayne/jw-sketch-plugins/  but there's an update there from 2 years ago saying: "Updated text plugins to work with Sketch 40" (probably means 4.0.). If that doesn't work in your Sketch version, you may want to search for "Sketch app text split plugin" and you may find something that I couldn't find.  That's all I can give you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for sketch which exactly do this. It is splitting one text box with multiple lines into multiple layers and also vice versa combine multiple layers to one text box with multiple lines. 
I am currently working with Sketch 50.2. and it is working quite nice - at least the splitting.

https://github.com/joshwayne/jw-sketch-plugins

Comment: Hi Schnitzelweck, could you please explain what we'll find behind the link and why it answers the question? It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.